# Removing rows from pandas df based on dates from two different columns

Tags: pandas, database

I have a pandas df that looks similar to this for all trading days of the year for multiple years for multiple trades. An example of one trade in the df is...

```
TICKER Price Date  TradeDate
A      12.30 01/02 01/31
A      45.70 01/03 01/31
A      78.90 01/04 01/31
A      12.70 01/05 01/31
...
A      31.10 02/01 01/31
A      23.20 02/02 01/31
B      12.30 02/01 02/20
B      45.70 02/02 02/20
B      78.90 02/03 02/20
B      12.70 02/04 02/20
...
B      31.10 02/27 02/20
B      23.20 02/28 02/20
```

For the next trade in the df, the only change is the trade date.

I want to filter the df to only include the rows that are -5 through +5 days of the trade date.

The ideal outcome would be this...

```
TICKER Price Date  TradeDate
A      45.70 01/26 01/31
A      78.90 01/27 01/31
A      12.70 01/28 01/31
A      12.70 01/29 01/31
A      12.70 01/30 01/31
A      31.10 01/31 01/31
A      23.20 02/01 01/31
A      27.03 02/02 01/31
A      36.78 02/03 01/31
A      69.10 02/04 01/31
A      38.45 02/05 01/31
...
B      35.79 02/15 02/20
B      46.57 02/16 02/20
B      16.80 02/17 02/20
B      90.46 02/18 02/20
B      85.16 02/19 02/20
B      50.29 02/20 02/20
B      24.78 02/21 02/20
B      23.90 02/22 02/20
B      91.26 02/23 02/20
B      38.56 02/24 02/20
B      67.01 02/25 02/20
...
```

Part of the issue I'm running into is accounting for business days. I've tried this...

```
df = df.drop(df[(((df.Date+ pd.tseries.offsets.BusinessDay(n = 5)) >= df.TradeDate) | ((nexttest.Date+ pd.tseries.offsets.BusinessDay(n = -5)) <= df.TradeDate))])
```

Do I need to loop through based on each day (e.g. -5,-4,-3,...,4,5)? What is the best way to account for business days as well?

Comment: I essentially want to remove all the rows from the DF that aren't within -5 to +5 of the trade date (days -5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5 of the trade date). There are multiple trade dates in the DF though (based on an identifier, such as CUSIP)

Comment: make example by using `date_range` and random with seeds. we need reproducibility. (and i think n day=3 is enough in example)

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, convert to datetime, then build masks and use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
# only if not already a datetime dtype
trade = pd.to_datetime('2024'+df['TradeDate'], format='%Y%m/%d')
date  = pd.to_datetime('2024'+df['Date'], format='%Y%m/%d')

# building masks
m1 = date >= trade-pd.offsets.BusinessDay(n = 5)
m2 = date <= trade+pd.offsets.BusinessDay(n = 5)

# selecting rows to keep
out = df[m1&m2]
```

Output:

```
   Price   Date TradeDate
4   31.1  02/01     01/31
5   23.2  02/02     01/31
```

Intermediates:

```
   Price   Date TradeDate       date      trade  trade-5BD  trade+5BD     m1    m2  m1&m2
0   12.3  01/02     01/31 2024-01-02 2024-01-31 2024-01-24 2024-02-07  False  True  False
1   45.7  01/03     01/31 2024-01-03 2024-01-31 2024-01-24 2024-02-07  False  True  False
2   78.9  01/04     01/31 2024-01-04 2024-01-31 2024-01-24 2024-02-07  False  True  False
3   12.7  01/05     01/31 2024-01-05 2024-01-31 2024-01-24 2024-02-07  False  True  False
4   31.1  02/01     01/31 2024-02-01 2024-01-31 2024-01-24 2024-02-07   True  True   True
5   23.2  02/02     01/31 2024-02-02 2024-01-31 2024-01-24 2024-02-07   True  True   True
```

Comment: i think OP's business day is not freq 'B' day

Comment: @PandaKim not sure I understood your comment, I used the same offset as theirs.

Comment: Though OP use function about freq 'B', OP's desired output is different.

Comment: I have prices for each trading day of the entire year. I don't need all the days though, just the days that are within -5/+5 days of making a trade. So I'm looking to keep the following days [-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5] based on each trade date.

Answer (score 0):

**Example Code**

we need reproducible example to answer

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
date = pd.date_range('2020-01-26', '2020-02-25').strftime('%m/%d')
np.random.seed(0)
price = np.random.randint(0, 10, 31)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Price': price, 'Date': date, 
                   'TradeDate': (['01/31'] * 20) + (['02/20'] * 11)})
```

df

```
    Price   Date TradeDate
0       5  01/26     01/31
1       0  01/27     01/31
2       3  01/28     01/31
3       3  01/29     01/31
4       7  01/30     01/31
5       9  01/31     01/31
6       3  02/01     01/31
7       5  02/02     01/31
8       2  02/03     01/31
9       4  02/04     01/31
10      7  02/05     01/31
11      6  02/06     01/31
12      8  02/07     01/31
13      8  02/08     01/31
14      1  02/09     01/31
15      6  02/10     01/31
16      7  02/11     01/31
17      7  02/12     01/31
18      8  02/13     01/31
19      1  02/14     01/31
20      5  02/15     02/20
21      9  02/16     02/20
22      8  02/17     02/20
23      9  02/18     02/20
24      4  02/19     02/20
25      3  02/20     02/20
26      0  02/21     02/20
27      3  02/22     02/20
28      5  02/23     02/20
29      0  02/24     02/20
30      2  02/25     02/20
```

---

**Code**

If all dates exist without exception and there are multiple trade days, try this code.

```
cond = df['Date'].eq(df['TradeDate'])
idx = df.where(cond).ffill(limit=5).bfill(limit=5).dropna().index
out = df[df.index.isin(idx)]
```

out:

```
    Price   Date TradeDate
0       5  01/26     01/31
1       0  01/27     01/31
2       3  01/28     01/31
3       3  01/29     01/31
4       7  01/30     01/31
5       9  01/31     01/31
6       3  02/01     01/31
7       5  02/02     01/31
8       2  02/03     01/31
9       4  02/04     01/31
10      7  02/05     01/31
20      5  02/15     02/20
21      9  02/16     02/20
22      8  02/17     02/20
23      9  02/18     02/20
24      4  02/19     02/20
25      3  02/20     02/20
26      0  02/21     02/20
27      3  02/22     02/20
28      5  02/23     02/20
29      0  02/24     02/20
30      2  02/25     02/20
```